# Setup a project and application for Google Drive

Tags: google-drive-api, google-drive-realtime-api

In the [instructions](https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-ios) for enabling the drive API, I can't seem to find the options in step 4 and 5:

1. In the sidebar on the left, select Registered apps.
2. Select an application.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1. Go to your projects** [here](https://cloud.google.com/console/project)
[image]

**2. Select your project or create new one**
 [image]

**3. Enable Drive API**
[image]